# Zebra imz320 zpl bluetooth printer "ZSDK_API_ERROR_DOMAIN" - code: 1 error

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, zebra-printers, zpl

I am trying to make an extension on my iOS app with Zebra iMZ320 printer. I followed developers guide of zebra. However ı got an error about SDK.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
NSString *serialNumber = @"";
//Find the Zebra Bluetooth Accessory
EAAccessoryManager *sam = [EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager];
NSArray * connectedAccessories = [sam connectedAccessories];
for (EAAccessory *accessory in connectedAccessories) {
    if([accessory.protocolStrings indexOfObject:@"com.zebra.rawport"] != NSNotFound){
        serialNumber = accessory.serialNumber;
        break;
        //Note: This will find the first printer connected! If you have multiple Zebra printers connected, you should display a list to the user and have him select the one they wish to use
    }
}
// Instantiate connection to Zebra Bluetooth accessory
id<ZebraPrinterConnection, NSObject> thePrinterConn = [[MfiBtPrinterConnection alloc] initWithSerialNumber:serialNumber];

// Open the connection - physical connection is established here.
BOOL success = [thePrinterConn open];

// This example prints "This is a ZPL test." near the top of the label.
NSString *zplData = @"^XA^FO20,20^A0N,25,25^FDThis is a ZPL test.^FS^XZ";

NSError *error = nil;
// Send the data to printer as a byte array.
success = success && [thePrinterConn write:[zplData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] error:&error];

if (success != YES || error != nil) {
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}
```

}

However when I try to print I got an error from last `NSError` variable. It is in write function.

```
domain: "ZSDK_API_ERROR_DOMAIN" - code: 1
```

Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, and my solution was to make a function with the code provided by ZEBRA and call this function in a different thread on the button that the user presses.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(sendZplByBluetooth) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

-(void)sendZplByBluetooth{
//Zebra Code Here
}
```

It was very expensive to realize that, I hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [zebra-toolkit](https://github.com/diegoCath/zebra-toolkit). It will save you a lot of trouble with managing the printer and using ZPL.